# Shared Axis Transition for Animated Switcher?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Is there a way I can get the horizontal axis sliding page transition with `AnimatedSwitcher`?

I want to keep my background static so I am using `AnimatedSwitcher` instead of `Navigator`, how do I then have a sliding animation using `AnimatedSwitcher`, similar to the `SharedAxisTransition` in the animations package?

```
Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
        children: [
            SizedBox(
                height: screenHeight,
                width: screenWidth,
                child: Container(), // Contains a color so the background is set
            ),
            OtherWidgetsHere(),
        ],
    )
)
```

What I do now is, I change `OtherWidgetsHere()` to a different widget with `AnimatedSwitcher`, but it does not have animations like `SharedAxisTransition`.

How do I use `Navigator` to change each `Scaffold` but keep a background image constant, so that only above elements fade through?

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet what you;ve tried so far and an attachment what are you trying to build.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Updated with your request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do what you want, but not exactly using `AnimatedSwitcher`. This is because `AnimatedSwitcher` is symmetrical - when a child is added it plays the animation, and when the child is removed it plays the same animation in reverse. `SharedAxisTransform` has different animations for entering and leaving so can't fit into an `AnimatedSwitcher`.

Fortunately, the [animations](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) package contains a widget [`PageTransitionSwitcher`](https://pub.dev/documentation/animations/latest/animations/PageTransitionSwitcher-class.html) which does the same thing as `AnimatedSwitcher` but for the asymmetrical animations in the animations package.

I made this utility widget to make it easy to use:

```dart
class SharedAxisSwitcher extends StatelessWidget {
  const SharedAxisSwitcher({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageTransitionSwitcher(
      child: child,
      transitionBuilder: (
        Widget child,
        Animation<double> primaryAnimation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      ) {
        return SharedAxisTransition(
          animation: primaryAnimation,
          secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
          transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Use it the same way as `AnimatedSwitcher` - by changing the `child` widget:

```dart
class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  const Demo({super.key});

  @override
  createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  var index = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SharedAxisSwitcher(
          child: Text(
            "Child #$index",
            // note - changing the key is necessary to get the child animation
            // if the type of the child (`Text` here) does not change
            key: Key("$index"),
          ),
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: const Text("Next child"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              index++;
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```